# Redirect all (root domain) links to corresponding links at subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So, I'd like to move the site I currently have at `example.com` to a subdomain `v1.example.com` so that I could use the main domain to work on a new version.

Is it possible (and how) to redirect automatically all links like `example.com/article-title-here` to the same link but on the subdomain - `v1.example.com/article-title-here`? And could it be done for all but my IP address only (so that I could still work on `example.com`?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that your IP is `127.0.0.1`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://v1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```